# Two disjoint open subsets

Tags: general-topology

Suppose that $X$ is a Hausdorff locally Euclidean topological space. Let $W$ be an open subset of $X$ and $p$ a point of $X$ such that $p\not\in W$. Can we find an open subset $V\subset X$ containing $p$ such that $V\cap W = \emptyset$ ?

Comment: Hint: think about the definition of a Hausdorff space.

Comment: I did, but I don`t know how to write it properly.

Comment: if $X$ is Hausdorff and $p,q\in X$ then there are disjoint open sets $U,V$ such that $p\in U$ and $q\in V$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, take $X=\Bbb R$, $W=(0,1)$, $p=1$. As $p \in \overline{W}$, no such $V$ exists.

Answer (score 1):

Take $X=\Bbb R$, $p=0$ and $V=\Bbb R-\{0\}$. Then any open subset $W\subset X$ containing $p$ intersects $V$.